# Header not Getting Injected into Request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm using a SOAPHandler and here's my `getHeaders` method at the client side:

```java
@Override
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    String uri = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    QName security_hdr = new QName(uri, "Security", "wsse");
    HashSet<QName> headers = new HashSet<QName>();
    headers.add(security_hdr);
    System.out.println("Headers: " + headers);
    return headers;
}
```

The SystemOut in the above line produces this code, so definitely I did return something from my method:

```
Headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security]
```

However, when trying to capture the request in **TCPMon**, I don't see the header at all.

```xml
POST /ws/server HTTP/1.1
Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
Soapaction: ""
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
Host: 127.0.0.1:4027
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 170

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><ns2:getServerName xmlns:ns2="http://ws.ronixus.com/"/></S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I've already commented out code from the other callback method `handleMessage` to make sure there's nothing overwriting the header.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this in handleMessage, just to confirm?

```
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();

Iterator headers = soapHeader.extractAllHeaderElements();
while(headers.hasNext() ){
    SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = (SOAPHeaderElement) headers.next();

    Name name = headerElement.getElementName();
    System.out.println(name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yup, `soapHeader` is null.

Comment: It seems the callBack from HandlerProcessor wasn't able to set it successfully (scratching head).